# Asymptotic behavior of median of number of prime divisors

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of positive integers, and let ${\bf P}\subseteq {\mathbb N}$ be the set of prime numbers. For $a\in \mathbb{N}$ let $$p(a) = \{p\in {\bf P}: (\exists k\in\mathbb{N})k\cdot p = a\}.$$ So we have $p(1)=0$, and $p(n) > 1$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$.

For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $\text{med}(n)$ be the *median* of the set $\{p(a): 1\leq a \leq n\}$.

**Questions.** Is the sequence $(\text{med}(n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ bounded? If yes, does it have a limit, and is the (integer) value of the limit known?

Comment: The median is certainly unbounded, and grows like $\gg \log\log n$. This follows from the fact (Hardy-Ramanujan, reproved by Turan) that $p(a)=(1+o(1))\log\log a$ for almost all integers $a$.

Comment: Are you counting the number of distinct prime divisors? Is $p(2^{5})=1$? Is $p(2^{5})=5$? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function

Comment: That's right, Joseph, only distinct prime divisors, so $p(2^5) = 1$. Will edit the original question

Comment: @JosephVanName the result cited by Thomas works for both